# Is it possible to deploy destructive change and new metadata in the same package.xml

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, destructivechanges.xml

Is it possible for exemple to deploy, in the same package, the action of destruct a field and create another in the same time?

Or I need to deploy 2 differents packages in two times: 
- one to destruct the fields i want to delete 
- one to create my fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm) you can do both in a single deployment.

**Adding and Deleting Components in a Single Deployment**

You can perform a deployment that specifies components to delete in destructiveChanges.xml and components to add or update in package.xml. The process is the same as with performing a delete-only deployment except that package.xml contains the components to add or update.

By default, deletions are processed before component additions. In API version 33.0 and later, you can specify components to be deleted before and after component additions. The process is the same as with performing a delete-only deployment except that the name of the deletion manifest file is different.

- To delete components before adding or updating other components,
  create a manifest file that’s named destructiveChangesPre.xml and
  include the components to delete.
- To delete components after adding     or updating other components,
  create a manifest file that’s named       destructiveChangesPost.xml
  and include the components to delete.